# FusionTables Update Query Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I'm building a FusionTables map with a drop down menu. I want the markers on the map to change based on the user selection in the drop down menu. Each menu selection corresponds with the three options of the "Possibility" column in the Fusion Table. I'm using these links as reference:

http://sportstleo12.appspot.com/ and https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query

I've copied the code and so far I can get all of the options to show, but it will not filter the results based on the user selection. I'm sure it's something simple. Any ideas?

here is the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Test Page 18</title>

<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"

 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<style>

body {
font-family: sans-serif;
background-image: url(images/squairy_light.png);
}

#main-container {
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #E0E0E0;
width:1280px;
margin: auto;
border-radius:3px;
padding-top: 15px;
background-color: white;
}
#map-canvas { 
    width:1250px; 
    height:600px; 
    margin: auto;
    }
#drop-down {
width:1250px;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;

}
#title {
width:1280px;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
font: sans-serif;
}

.layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };

</style>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script src="/path/to/fusiontips_compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


function initialize() {

var tableId = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ';
var locationColumn = 'Lat/Long';

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {

center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 345),

zoom: 3,

mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

});

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: locationColumn,
        from: tableId,
      },
      map: map,
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('option-list'),
        'change', function() {
          updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn);
    });
  }

  // Update the query sent to the Fusion Table Layer based on
  // the user selection in the select menu
  function updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn) {
    var delivery = document.getElementById('option-list').value;
    if (delivery) {
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId,
          where: "option-list = '" + delivery + "'"
        }
      });
    } else {
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId
        }
      });
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>


</head>

<body>



<div id="title"><h1>Possibility Options</h1></div>
<div id="main-container">

<div id="map-canvas"></div>



<div id="drop-down">

<label>Possibilities:</label>

<select id="option-list">

<option value="">--All Possibilities--</option>

<option value="Yes">Yes</option>

<option value="No">No</option>

<option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>


</select>
</div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please post your answer as an _answer_ not as part of the question.  It would also be useful if you described what the problem was and what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what was wrong with the code I previously posted. I found this link that helped me to write it differently and solce my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/vw4YC/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Test Page 18</title>

<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"

rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<style>

body {
font-family: sans-serif;
background-image: url(images/squairy_light.png);
}

#main-container {
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #E0E0E0;
width:1280px;
margin: auto;
border-radius:3px;
padding-top: 15px;
background-color: white;
}
#map-canvas { 
    width:1250px; 
    height:600px; 
    margin: auto;
    }
#drop-down {
width:1250px;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;

}
#title {
width:1280px;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
font: sans-serif;
}

.layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };

</style>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script src="/path/to/fusiontips_compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var tableId = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ';

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'Lat/Long',
        from: tableId,
      },
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2,
    });


function initialize() {


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {

center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 345),

zoom: 3,

mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

});
layer.setMap(map);
}


//Change the query based on the user's selection
function changeMap() {
    possibility = document.getElementById('Possibility').value;
    where = " Possibility LIKE '%" + possibility + "%'";

    layer.setOptions({
        query: {
            select: 'Lat/Long',
            from: tableId,
            where: where
        }
    });
}

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>


</head>

<body>



<div id="title"><h1>Possibility Options</h1></div>
<div id="main-container">

<div id="map-canvas"></div>



<div id="drop-down">

<label for="Possibility">Possibilities:</label>

<select id="Possibility" onChange="changeMap();">

<option value="">--All Possibilities--</option>

<option value="Yes">Yes</option>

<option value="No">No</option>

<option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>


</select>
</div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```